# Why can't I change my input value in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a recipe project and I want the user to add a recipe.

I'll add data via input but I cannot make any changes on "video URL" and "ingCount" inputs. I do not understand why this is so. **Other inputs work fine and they work smoothly.**.

I just can't enter values into ***ingCount and videoLink.***

*** Their names on the API are also correct.

[image: example]

```
const [addRecipe, setAddRecipe] = useState({
    id: "",
    title: "",
    description: "",
    image: "",
    category: "",
    time: 0,
    ingCount: 0,
    servings: 0,
    videoLink: "",
    ingredients: "",
    makeDetails: ""
  })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setAddRecipe({
      id: Math.random() * 100,
      ...addRecipe,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setRecipes([...recipes, addRecipe])
    axios
      .post(
        "https://5fccb170603c0c0016487102.mockapi.io/api/recipes",
        addRecipe
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    setAddRecipe(addRecipe)
    console.log(handleSubmit)
  }
```

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              value={addRecipe.title}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="baslik giriniz"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="description"
              value={addRecipe.description}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="tarif aciklamasi"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="category"
              value={addRecipe.category}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="kategori"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="time"
              value={addRecipe.time}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="süre"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="malzeme"
              value={addRecipe.ingCount}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="malzeme sayısı"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="servings"
              value={addRecipe.servings}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="kişilik"
            />
          </div>

          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="ingredients"
              value={addRecipe.ingredients}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="malzemeler"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="makeDetails"
              value={addRecipe.makeDetails}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="yapilisi"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="image"
              value={addRecipe.image}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="resim"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="video"
              value={addRecipe.videoLink}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="video"
            />
          </div>
          <button className="todoform__btn" type="submit">
            Tarifi ekle!
          </button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are the only two fields where the `name` doesn't match with the `value` property. For the `ingCount` you have `malzeme` as the name. And for `videoLink` you have `video` as the name.

So for those, when

```
    setAddRecipe({
      id: Math.random() * 100,
      ...addRecipe,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
```

is called, you are setting a property that will never be used.

Answer (score 1):

The name has to be same in input field and object name.
Currently for these its different ->

```
       <input
          type="text"
          name="video". //should be video Link
          value={addRecipe.videoLink}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="video"
        />
```

Update this it will resolve your issue.
Also I will suggest you to use callback inside setState. Otherwise all the fields might not get saved in the state.

setState (prev => ({...prev, key: value})

Comment: I'm grateful for ur help! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting state values using "name" attribute, for ingCount and video, "name" attributes in input fields are different than state hence its not getting updated.

```html
<input type="number" name="ingCount" value={addRecipe.ingCount} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="malzeme sayısı" />
<input type="text" name="videoLink" value={addRecipe.videoLink} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="video" />
```